# Error when trying to store random element from array in variable Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, ios9

I have an array of area codes and I am trying store a random element from the array in a variable and I get an error "instance member 'areaCodes' can not be used on type 'ViewController' ". Any suggestions?

```
var areaCodes = [209, 213, 310, 323, 408, 415]
var firstThree = areaCodes[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(areaCodes.count)))]
```

Comment: Please show where/how you're doing this in your view controller. There is currently not enough information to understand what it wrong. Sidenote: Your code works in a playground

Comment: Those two lines work fine on swiftstub, so more context is needed to understand your problem.

Comment: It crashes always or sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access your array at initialization time. Change your property to a read only computed property:

```
var firstThree: Int { return areaCodes[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(areaCodes.count)))] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the `firstThree` variable inside a function of your class.