# Reference to generic type 'Dictionary' requires arguments in <..>

Tags: swift

I have the following function:

```
func createEventDictionaryFromType(type: String) -> Dictionary<String, Double> {
var DurationsArray = [0.1, 3.4, 5.1]
if (type == "k"){
    var durationIndex = arc4random_uniform(3)
    return ["duration" : DurationsArray[Int(durationIndex)]]
}
if (type == "g"){
    var durationIndex = arc4random_uniform(3)
    return ["duration" : DurationsArray[Int(durationIndex)]]

}

}
```

I see this SO post: [Swift error: Reference to generic type Dictionary requires arguments in <...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728350/swift-error-reference-to-generic-type-dictionary-requires-arguments-in)

However I don't know why I am still getting the error , as I have , to my knowledge, followed the solution to the former post.

Comment: why is it optional? And how do I unwrap it?

Comment: The problem there is that arc4random_uniform method returns a UInt32 you need to coerce it to Int to use it as an index for your array

Comment: But i still get the error after I cast the Index as `Int()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35077599/2303865

Comment: Look at the paragraph `Numeric Type Conversion` in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: Your updated code gives the error "missing return ..." because the function does not return anything if the type is neither "k" nor "g". Please show your exact code and exact error message.